# shield ui charts disappeare after upgrading .net framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, shieldui

I am using Shield UI 1.7.2, and .Net Framework 3.5, everything was okay, but when I upgraded .net to 4.0, the shield ui charts disappear sometimes when I do postback ( chart html removed from page ), and become visible again after page finishes loading !

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you are using the correct DLLs (from the .NET40 directory of the package).
Also, inspect if there are any JavaScript errors on the browser console when posting back...

Last, if you are a commercial license owner, you can email those guys - they have great support and will fix your problem almost immediately.

Comment: there is no js errors, how do i know that i am using the correct dll ? is it different from .net version to another ?